# Is it possible to make relation with additional field?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'd like to know is it possible to make relation between two entities but add additional field which doesn't exists in related entity.

Here is Person entity-schema

```
@Schema({ collection: 'persons', timestamps: true })
export class Person {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
...
  @Prop({
  type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Sign.name }],
  })
  @Type(() => Sign)
  signOfPerson: Sign[];
}
```

And Sign entity-schema

```
@Schema({ collection: 'signs', timestamps: true })
export class Sign {
  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  name: string;
}
```

All works fine but i need add to each person sign additional information about date when person got each his sign, and i don't understand how to do it? Is there way to avoid additional entity between Person and Sign and hold this date right in Person sign list?

I see that creation of new entity (PersonSign) will solve the problem, but i'm very interesting is it possible to do it without that? Any help will be appreciated.